# How to mount google storage into our local using gcsfs?

Tags: centos, google-cloud-storage

I am new to GCS (google cloud storage),I am using CentOS 6.5, I need mount GCS to our local.

already installed GSUTIL and GCSFS.

Please help me how to mount the GCS to our local system through gcsfs.

Thanks,

Prasad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah Finally i got the solution.

mount to locally

gcsfs -f mountpoint(/mnt/test)

Now i am able to copy,edit and delete files in gcs(from local mount point).

note:- Files are copied successfully but end of the executing command it will give Input/output error ,commit error is getting. but files are copied successfully.

Please suggest the solution for errors.

Thanks,

Prasad